# How to add a strings with a numberical value in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

In my laravel controller, I get phone number from user input (01711111111). I want to add country code (88) with the user input, so total result will be like 880171111111. How can I add a string with the numerical value? This code shows error.

```
$client_phone=$request->phone_number;
$client_phone1='88'+$client_phone;
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php#:~:text=String%20Operators%20%C2%B6&text=The%20first%20is%20the%20concatenation,argument%20on%20the%20left%20side.

Comment: If you state that there is an array, could you share that error?

Answer (score 1):

**concatenation operator** ('.')

```
$client_phone1 = '88' . $client_phone;
```